# Digite um número e exiba os próximos 100 números pares

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um programa que recebe um número qualquer e exibe os próximos 100 números pares, porém assim que abro o site ele já esta exibindo um resultado sem nem digitar nada.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-bt">

<head>
    <title>Exercicio 3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="css/exercicio3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <!--Barra de Navegação-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Exercicios de PHP</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Exercicio 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="exercicio2.php">Exercicio 2</a></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exercicio 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exercicio 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <h3 class="page_header">Exercicio 3</h3>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                <div class="area_conteudo">
                    <h4 class="title_form">Faça o calculo a baixo</h4><br>

                    <form class="posicao" name="formulario" method="GET" action="exercicio3.php">
                        <label>Digite um valor inteiro</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" id="tamanho" class="form-control " name="numero" placeholder="Digite um numero">
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Calcular">
                    </form>

                    <h3 class="texto_resultado">Resultado:</h3>


                    <!--PHP-->

                    <?php 
                    $numero = $_GET['numero'];
                    $c = 0;
                    while ($c <= 100) {
                      if ($numero % 2 == 0) {
                        echo "$numero ";
                      }
                      $numero++;
                      $c++;
                    }

                    ?>

                    <!--FIM-PHP-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O número está na URL provavelmente. Pois o método que você usa é `$_GET`.

Comment: Sua url deve estar tipo assim: `exercicio3.php?numero=12` certo?

Answer (score 4):

O `$_GET` é uma variável seper global que contêm os valores da *query string* da URL

*Query String* são todos os caracteres após a interogação ("?")

O que provavelmente acontece é que você está passando esse valor direto pela URL e não através do formulário

Um forma simples de evitar isso é usar o verbo HTTP POST no lugar do GET:

```
<!-- ... -->
<form class="posicao" name="formulario" method="POST" action="exercicio3.php">
    <label>Digite um valor inteiro</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" id="tamanho" class="form-control " name="numero" placeholder="Digite um numero">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Calcular">
</form>

<h3 class="texto_resultado">Resultado:</h3>

<!--PHP-->

<?php 
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$c = 0;
while ($c <= 100) {
  if ($numero % 2 == 0) {
    echo "$numero ";
  }
  $numero++;
  $c++;
}
// ...
```

Assim a variável `numero` será enviada pelo corpo da requisição e não mais pela URL

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367732/112052) já explica a causa provável do seu programa exibir o resultado sem você digitar nada. Só gostaria de sugerir uma melhoria no seu algoritmo.

Se você quer iterar pelos números pares, não precisa somar de um em um e testar se é par. Basta você começar por um número par e ir somando de 2 em 2:

```
$numero = // obter o valor do número

// pega o próximo número par (mas se já for par, não incrementa)
$numero += ($numero % 2);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 100; $i++) {
  echo "$numero ";
  $numero += 2; // pega o próximo número par
}
```

Sobre a linha `$numero += ($numero % 2)`:

- se o número for par (se `$numero % 2` é zero), será somado zero (ou seja, o número já é par, posso começar por ele mesmo)
- se o número for ímpar (se `$numero % 2` não é zero - e portanto será 1), eu somo 1 (para que o número comece com o próximo valor par)

Assim, eu garanto que o `for` sempre começará a partir de um número par. Claro que você também pode trocar esta linha por:

```
// se for ímpar, ajusta para o próximo número par
if ($numero % 2 != 0) {
    $numero++;
}
```

Escolha o que achar melhor.

---

Dentro do `for` eu imprimo o número e somo 2 para obter o próximo número par (e faço isso 100 vezes).

Se quiser, pode até incrementar o número juntamente com o `$i`:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 100; $i++, $numero += 2) {
  echo "$numero ";
}
```

---

Outro ponto é que seu código não está fazendo o que deveria:

```
$c = 0;
while ($c <= 100) {
  if ($numero % 2 == 0) {
    echo "$numero ";
  }
  $numero++;
  $c++;
}
```

Se o número é par, imprime. Mas ele sempre incrementa `$c`, mesmo se o número não for par. O resultado é que serão impressos apenas 50 números pares (ou 51 se começar em um número par, por causa do `<=`).

Para corrigir, basta pensar o que o `$c` significa: ele está contando a quantidade de números pares que foram impressos. Então você só pode incrementar `$c` se o número for par. E eu devo parar se o valor dele chegar a 100 (portanto, o `while` deve usar `<` em vez de `<=`):

```
$c = 0;
while ($c < 100) {
  if ($numero % 2 == 0) {
    echo "$numero ";
    $c++; // só incrementa $c se o número for par
  }
  $numero++;
}
```

Com isso serão impressos 100 números pares corretamente. Mas ainda prefiro a opção que sugeri acima, pois não há necessidade de iterar de 1 em 1 e fazer um `if` a cada iteração.

Answer (score 1):

Para exibir 100 próximos números pares, eu faria algo assim:

```
$numero = $_GET['numero'];
                $inicio = 0;
                $fim = 100;
                while ($inicio<= $fim) {
                  if ($numero % 2 == 0) {
                    echo "$numero ";
                    $inicio++
                  }
                  $numero++;
                }
                ?>
```

Desta forma ele fará os 100 loops, e irá checar qual número é o par. uma outra opção, que diminuiria o tempo de processo do php seria assim:

```
$numero = $_GET['numero'];
                $fim = $numero + 200;
                while ($numero<= $fim) {
                  if ($numero % 2 == 0)
                      {
                                echo "<br>".$numero;
                      }    
                  elseif ($numero % 2 != 0)
                      {
                                $numero++;
                                echo "<br>".$numero;
                      }    

                $numero= $numero +2;
                }
                ?>
```

Nesse esquema, ele irá pular para o número par. Caso inicie de um número ímpar, ele irá considerar, somar um, e então prosseguir com o mesmo processo.

Comment: Com as dicas eu consegui arrumar, muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada, se puder marcar uma das respostas como correta, para que outra pessoa que outra pessoa com o mesmo problema encontre a mesma ajuda que você procurou de forma mais fácil